# Amazon SNS endpoint arn seems wrong.

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

So I am using the amazon sns SDK and have gotten the code to run properly to get a push notification on the amazon device. The problem is that I am not getting a push notification on the device. What I think is the problem is that the endpoint Arn is incorrect for some reason because when I run the program the endpoint is giving me a west location and if I register the device using the amazon console the endpoint Arn is different and giving me an east location. Does anyone know why I am getting two different endpoints and how to maybe hard code the endpoint to check if that is the issue.

Comment: I think u need to set region explicitly. That will solve this problem

Comment: Can you select the correct region in the AWS dashboard before registering the device?

Comment: Show some code, please.  You need to be *calling* the correct regional service endpoint.